# Pygame not working on mac, console says no module called pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "alien_invasion.py", line 3, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Console says there is no module named pygame, but I've downloaded pygame already and IDLE allows me to import pygame and use it.

Comment: This often happens if you have different Python versions on your computer, so you could have installed pygame for Python 3 and you're trying to import it in Python 2. Enter `python` in the console and check which version it is and then check which version IDLE uses. I think you have to enter `python3` in the console to start Python 3 on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

In the console you can use the command `python --version` to see the default version of Python you are running. Most likely what is happening is you have a different version of Python running in the console than you do in IDLE. You can specify when you run it.

Try each of these in the console:

`python2 alien_invasion.py`

or

`python3 alien_invasion.py`

Comment: thanks! the python3 command worked for me. game is running smoothly now.